# Xbox Arcade Games subscription requirements

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, xbox-live-arcade

I am trying to figure out what are the requirements to download and play Xbox Arcade Games. My nephew asked me to buy for his birthday Castle Crashers for Xbox 360, but he doesn't have an Xbox Gold subscription and he doesn't have the Xbox connected to internet.

Is the Xbox Gold subscription needed in order to buy this kind of games? If not and if he connects the console to internet only to complete the registration process, buy the game and download it, is possible to play the game if he disconnects later on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Xbox 360 you are able to purchase games without having a gold subscription, of course you do require internet to be able to purchase and install the game. Once you have the game downloaded you are free to play the game no matter what happens to the internet connection. The only exception being of course playing games online multiplayer which of course requires an XBox Live Gold subscription.